# How to customise bootstrap icon

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to customise linkedIn icon from bootstrap. I want to add link, size and colour.
How can I do it please ?

```
<i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the bootstrap docs?

Answer (score 0):

for link use a tag like:

```
<a href="your url">
  <i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
</a>
```

but you need destroying a tag default styles.

and for size & color you can use css:

```
i{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
}
```

**or**

```
.bi{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bootstrap built in classes like you can have `yellow` color background and `green` color font in this way;

```
<i class="bi bi-linkedin bg-warning text-success"></i>
```

Apart from the colors provided in the bootstrap, you can add your custom colors also.

If you want to customize the icon to use it over button/button group, or in heading/small heading or with input field refer the examples [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/linkedin/)